# serializeArray on keyless array input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, multidimensional-array

If I have a form with a keyless array as one of the names like so:

```
<form id="form">
    <input name="array[]" type="text" value="zero" />
    <input name="array[]" type="text" value="one" />
    <input name="array[]" type="text" value="two" />
    <input name="array[]" type="text" value="three" />
    <input name="single" type="text" value="something" />
</form>
```

and I ultimately want to turn in into a multidimensional array in PHP like so:

```
Array ( [array] => Array ( [0] => zero [1] => one [2] => two [3] => three ) [single] => something )
```

How can I do that in Javascript/jQuery without POSTing the form data?

Note: I'll be sending whatever data I get with jQuery to PHP with Ajax and don't need help with that part.  Really all I need is a method to package that form data in a way that I can eventually read with PHP.  It doesn't seem like serializeArray() or serialize() can do the trick. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Seems to me `serialize()` does the trick [just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ndXRH/).

Comment: Sorry mate but you're going to have to post your form to the server, if you want to process it with PHP. Just serialize the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('#form').serialize()` along with `$.post` to accomplish what you need to do.

For example:

```
$.post(url, $("#form").serialize());
```

I am not sure how else you would **post** the form data **without** posting the form data!

Comment: Well like you and bažmegakapa say, serialize() actually does work in conjunction with parse_str() on the PHP side.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php',
    data: $('#form').serialize()
});
```

or

```
$.post('submit.php',
    $('#form').serialize()
);
```